# Possibility to override (change args) of a super class method

Tags: typescript, inheritance, parent-child

I came across following issue, I have 2 classes i.e.

```
class Animal {
  public talk() {
    console.log('...');
  }
}
```

and

```
class Dog extends Animal {
  public talk(noise: string) {
    console.log(noise);
    super.talk()
  }
}
```

As you can see original `Animal.talk` method has no arguments and due to constraints of my application it can't have any, however some classes that extend it can take in additional `noise` argument. This throws a type error since this argument is not initially on Animal. Hence I wanted to ask how to handle this correctly.

This is a very simplified example, real use case has various types of `noise` and I'd like to avoid defining all of these as possible values of `Animal.talk` and ideally keep it without arguments;

Comment: why dont you just use talk(optional?: unknown): void ?

Comment: Can be done, still throws warning about unused arg, was hoping to avoid that, but if no answers are suggested will have to just go with it and add ts-disable comment I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is required that Dog accept both `talk("string")` and `talk()` in this case. If you pass a Dog to a function that takes an Animal, that function must be able to call `animal.talk()` (or else you've violated [substitutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). That means that `noise` has to be optional:

```
class Dog extends Animal {
  public talk(noise?: string) {
    console.log(noise);
    super.talk()
  }
}
```

And then you just need to then deal with cases where `noise` is not passed. (But that's not avoidable. You will always have to deal with cases where `noise` is not passed.)